# jQuery click only works once

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm using the http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/ script.

Here is the HTML (there are multiple `.team-member` on the page):

```
<div class="team-member">
    <div class="featured-photo"></div>
        <h3></h3>
        <h4></h4>
    <div class="member-info">
        <h5></h5>
        <p class="member-photo"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
jQuery('.team-member').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).children('.member-info').lightbox_me({
        centered: true
    });
});
</script>
```

I can click on each `.team-member` and the lightbox pops up and disappears when I click the page...just like it should, however I can only do that once. The lightbox doesn't pop up a second time if I click again. Any way around this?

Comment: Any errors on the console?

Comment: It'll be better if you can give a jsfiddle demo.

Comment: hey have you used `destroyOnClose : true` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because lightbox_me is moving the DOM element out of its initial location and appending it to the body prior to applying its styling. This is similar to how jQuery dialog behaves if you are familiar with that.

Because the selection is dependent on the parenting hierarchy, the next time the click event occurs, `jQuery(this).children('.member-info')` returns no matching objects and the call to lightbox_me fails.

You can get around this by cloning the object before lightboxing it and then setting the **destroyOnClose** flag to true.

```
jQuery('.team-member').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).children('.member-info').clone().lightbox_me({
        centered: true,
        destroyOnClose: true
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QpK7G/2/)

Comment: I used `destroyOnClose` to no avail. Using `clone()` as well was the trick. You have no idea how much I love you right now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

As you  have not provided any fiddle link I am not sure but you can try the below to see if it works

```
jQuery('.team-member').live('click',function() {
    jQuery(this).children('.member-info').lightbox_me({
        centered: true
    });
});
```